# How I can pass String to variable type URL in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I got something like this:

```
interface Base {
var url: URL?
}

class BaseImpl: Base {
override var url: URL? = null
}
```

Now in my test I want to pass this:
                    url = "http://www.countries-list.info/Download-List/download.txt"
but of course I got this error:
^ Type mismatch: inferred type is String but URL? was expected

Does anyone knows how it should be solved?
I know that URL object accept string as parameter URL(String spec)
but I don't know how to implement that in my case.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Problem is your interface in URL but you override with string value

override value  like this

```
 override var url: URL? = URL("http://www.countries-list.info/Download-List/download.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in my test I have this:
 url = "http://www.countries-list.info/Download-List/download.txt"
and I know this is working
 url = URL("http://www.countries-list.info/Download-List/download.txt")
but I don't want this, I want to handle this somehow in interface or implementation of interface. Because I don't want that user have to write url = URL("")

Comment: URLs and Strings are different things.  `URL()` is only 5 extra characters, and makes the types perfectly clear.  If you really need to avoid that, you'll have to change the property type in the interface, or add an overload property in the implementation with overridden getter and setter (or provide equivalent methods).  (Or find a way to provide URL values for the caller to use.)

Comment: Thank you, can you please provide with example how I can provide equivalent methods for that. I think this will be a proper solution.